# How do i create a function so that i can control the size of a group? so i can choose if i want to have 2 or 3 people in each group

Tags: javascript, arrays

I've gotten as far as this. I want to create a function so that i can create groups of 2 or 3 or 4.
when i do it like this i just get the first name in each group of the array as a P element printed on the page. How can i do it different?

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="classListSection"></div>

    <script>
      let longList = [alot of names..];

      const classList = document.getElementById("classListSection");
      function createListItem(index, value) {
        let newList = document.createElement("p");
        newList.innerHTML = index + value;
        classList.appendChild(newList);
      }


      function chunkArray(arr, val) {
        let finalArr = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i += val) {
          finalArr.push(arr.slice(i, val + i));
          createListItem(i, longList[i]);
        }
      }
      chunkArray(longList, 3);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What do you mean by different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're almost there. [`Array.prototype.slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) returns a part of the array without modifying the original. You just need to pass the result of that to your `createListItem` method

```js
let longList = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".split('');

const classList = document.getElementById("classListSection");
function createListItem(index, value) {
  let newList = document.createElement("p");
  newList.innerHTML = index + value;
  classList.appendChild(newList);
}


function chunkArray(arr, val) {
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i += val) {
    createListItem(i, arr.slice(i, i + val));
  }
}
chunkArray(longList, 3);
```

```html
<div id="classListSection"></div>
```

If you change that final line to `chunkArray(longList, 2);` there will be 2 items per group or `chunkArray(longList, 4);` there will be 4.